# Giving same variable twice in pass by value result

Tags: pass-by-value

What I'm trying to understand is when I pass same variable twice as a function arguement, is it copied twice also, in different memory locations?

Assume inout specifies pass-by-value-result.

```
void foo(inout int a, inout int b){
    a++;
    b++;
}
x = 2;
foo(x, x);
// x is 3
```

As pass by value result specifies, value of x should be copied, then incremented and assigned to x after function return. Here in this code, is x is copied twice, since foo function is called with parameters "x,x"? If it isn't, why does it remain 3 after two increment operations?

Comment: I'm no expert, but actually, I think that `x` should still be 2 after `foo`, and not 3 as you mention. You are passing it by value that, as you said, passes a copy of this variable, rather than the same instance (as  when you pass by refernce), but you return nothing from that function. so inside of the function, `a` and `b` gets incremented, but your original `x`, outside of the function's scope, remains unchanged. Your assumption, that `x` gets returned after the function, is wrong.

Comment: Dude, you really do not know pass-by-value-result, right?

Comment: Sorry, thought of it as pass-by-value. You are right mate, I don't know pass-by-value-result.

Comment: http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse505/99au/imperative/parameters.html

Comment: Have a look [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23246/what-is-pass-by-value-result-and-its-advantage-and-disadvantage) mate. Look around the middle, where it says 'Side effects and evaluation order'. The guy who asked the question also uses similair example as you, and the guy who answer, explained the issue with passing the same parameter in the section I've mentioned.